# Passing Array.push as an argument throws exception in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I tried to merge two arrays in JavaScript. I wrote a code like this:

```
var array1 = [1, 2];

var array2 = [3, 4];

array2.forEach(function(value) {
   array1.push(value);
});
```

I know there are better ways such as `array1 = array1.concat(array2);` and this question is not about it.

I tried to minimize the above code like this:

```
var array1 = [1, 2];

var array2 = [3, 4];

array2.forEach(array1.push);
```

It is same code but I do not create the extra unnamed function. I pass array1.push function directly to forEach.
I expected same result but I get this exception:

`Cannot convert undefined or null to object`

I do not understand why I am getting this exception?

Comment: You're passing the push function, and disconnecting it from the array you want to push into in the process.

Comment: even if that would work with `array2.forEach(Array.prototype.push.bind(array1));` you get all parameters of the callback pushed, like value, index and array for each loop.

Comment: For the best performance just use namedFunction, because bind() on each interation is not perfect as well